# Need to write a regex to parse the command

Tags: salesforce, apex

Need to write a regex to get 3 groups from strings-
`<whatever text including new lines optional -group 1>/command <text until \n or </p> is encountered- group 2><whatever text including new lines optional -group 3>`

what I tried is-
`Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile('(.*?)[/]command (.*?)\n?(.*?)');`

It should give the following output for string-
**some\nthing/command cmdtext/nasdfjaklsdjf\nfgskdlkfg\ndgsdfgsdfgsdfg**

group 1 - some\nthing
group 2 - cmdtext
group 3 - asdfjaklsdjf\nfgskdlkfg\ndgsdfgsdfgsdfg

What I am not getting is how to get the occurrence of `</p>` and .* is not considering the group. Although this is working for me-

```
String a = '\na\na\n\n\n\n\n\naaa';
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile('\n(?s:.)*');
Matcher mchr = GiphyPattern.matcher(a);
system.assert (mchr.matches());
```

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression should match what you need:

```
'([\\s\\S]*)/command (.*?)(?:\n|</p>)([\\s\\S]*)'
```

You cannot match `\n` with `.*` So I am using `\\s\\S` instead (which is actually `\s\S` but with Apex escaped backslashes).